# Cut off text exceeding a certain length

Tags: abap, sap-bsp

I have a list with texts with lengths ranging from 1 character to  several thousands. I want to cut off all texts exceeding 255 characters. How can I do that?
Do I have to check the length of each String and then cut it with (255) or is there a more elegant expression?

Edit: like this

```
<% IF STRLEN( wa_comm-text ) > 255. %>
<%= wa_comm-text(255) %> ...
<% ELSE. %>
<%= wa_comm-text %>
<% ENDIF. %>
```

this is BSP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other option is:

```
<% 
data: ls_text(255) type c. 
ls_text = wa_comm-text.   
%>
<%= ls_text %>
```

Because you obviously cannot use substrings on strings, and if they are shorter, you will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

I created for this a 'string solutions' class called zss, with a static method that will cut off a given string and the given length.

Then you can just do something like this:

```
<%= zss=>left( s = wa_comm-text cutoff = 255 ). %>
```

or even a more specific method

```
<%= zss=>left255(  wa_comm-text ). %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an option:

```
<%= CONV char255( wa_comm-text ) %>
```

inline conversion and trimming to target type is done here.